# Force SSL on one page via .htaccess without looping

Tags: ssl, .htaccess, redirect

Okay, I have this code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/borrowing/ill/request\.php$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

The way I would expect this to work is:

1. A request for /borrowing/ill/request.php comes in on HTTP.
2. The rule matches.
3. The server redirects to HTTPS.
4. The rule does not match, because HTTPS is now on.

The way it actually works is:

1. A request for /borrowing/ill/request.php comes in on HTTP.
2. The rule matches.
3. The server redirects to HTTPS.
4. The rule matches.
5. The server redirects to HTTPS.
6. The rule matches.
7. The server redirects to HTTPS ...

And so on.

I know that the second condition (matching the file name) is working, because the redirect loop only hits that specific page.  The question is, why isn't the switch to HTTPS causing the first condition to not match?

EDIT:

I put the exact same .htaccess rules into a test area on another server -- same file and path info.  And they worked *just fine*. There's got to be something wrong with the server configuration elsewhere.

Comment: If you enable verbose rewrite logging (via `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel`), do  you see anything unexpected?

Comment: I just tried this.  Unfortunately, I do not have shell access to the server, and setting `RewriteLog` to a file in one of the folders I can see causes a 500 Internal Server Error, probably because the Apache process doesn't have write permissions.  I can send it to /tmp fine, but can't retrieve the results. :-/  Maybe I should have asked this on Stackoverflow ...

Comment: Maybe, but I suspect even on StackOverflow people would ask you to do some basic diagnostics first.  You could presumably create a directory with permissions that would allow Apache to create a log file there.

Comment: I sure wish I could -- my only access to the server is through a crappy web-based interface built into a half-baked CMS.  I can create and upload directories/files, but it does not offer any way to control their perms.  It sucks.

Comment: @Will Where does this .htaccess located -- in website root folder ... or subfolder? Also -- can you upload any custom php script and execute it? You could try to use it to read the rewrite debug log and display it in browser...

Comment: @LazyOne I figure out what's causing the problem, and it's not the .htaccess -- see the answer I filed below.

Comment: Are there any other rewrite rules somewhere?

Comment: @Chris S. -- yes, but the problem is the load balancer which keep bouncing the SSL request back to a non-encrypted connection.

Comment: @Will, if the load balancer wont pass it through encrypted, you'll never be able to use this rule.

Comment: @Chris S Yes; not until the person who maintains the load balancer fixes its configuration, which is being worked on now that the problem has been reported. At worst, if they fail to load balance it, I'll use PHP to insert a META tag into any non-encrypted version of the page that causes it to refresh to the SSL version, with a timeout of zero seconds.  Which is ugly, but it will work.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that there is nothing wrong with the code above.  The problem is that the server I was executing it on is talking to a load balancer which only communicates on port 80.

So, the HTTPS request comes in on port 443, hits the load balancer, which redirects it to port 80.  Then the web server redirects it back to 443, which gets redirected to 80, to 443, to 80, to 443 ...

So, the fix is to report it to the person who maintains the load balancer and hope they can figure it out.

Thanks for the help anyway, you've all been very patient.

Comment: Thanks for leaving the answer to your problem for other people. You can go ahead and accept your own answer if you like.

Answer (score 0):

If the target domain is known, try this:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/borrowing/ill/request\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Alas, no. I get the same behavior with this as with my initial stanza.